# Python - Append to a copy variable

Tags: python

I've a list. I make the copy of that list. Now I want to append a number into its copy not into the original list. How would I do that?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b.append(4)

print a,b # prints [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want `[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4]`. How would I do that?

Comment: to make a copy: `b = a.copy()`

Comment: @behzad.nouri, It's only available in Python 3.3+, OP is using Python 2.x. (using `print` statement)

Comment: Did you attempt to search for, e.g., "python copy list"? Gives excellent results.

Comment: python 2.x has module `copy`; with which you can `b = copy.copy(a)`; in addition you can always copy the elements of the list `b = a[:]` rather than a reference to the list itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to copy the values, you should use

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3]
b = copy.copy(a)
b.append(4)

print a,b
```

Comment: @user1162512 If this answer helped you, please give it a +1 and accept it.

Comment: Easier to use `b = a[:]` to make a copy. No need to `import copy` (but no harm done this way either).

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use b = a[:] to copy a list.